# When this $d(x,y)=[(x_1-y_1)^{p_1} + (x_2-y_2)^{p_2}]^{f(p_1,p_2)}$ a metric? (Imbalance metric)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

We know in a very common situation metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as
$$ d(x,y) = [(x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2-y_2)^2]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Now suppose I defined a metric as follows;

$$d(x,y)=[(x_1-y_1)^{p_1} + (x_2-y_2)^{p_2}]^{f(p_1,p_2)}.$$

I called it *imbalance metric*. My question is how the function $f(p_1,p_2)$ looks like?

Comment: I presume you mean $d(x,y)=\big(|x_1-y_1|^{p_1}+|x_2-y_2|^{p_2}\big)^{f(p_1,p_2)}$, right? Because otherwise your $d$ is unlikely to be even symmetric for $p_1\neq p_2$.

Comment: @freakish yeah yeah.. sorry for the mistake, I edited...and thanks!